# Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext()

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

Please help, 
Get an error about reactive function near this code:

```
stockstxtclosure <- reactive({
    query <- parseQueryString(clientData$url_search)

    stockstweets = searchTwitter(query[["ticker"]], n=10, lang="en")
    stockstxt = sapply(stockstweets, function(x) x$getText())

    return (stockstxt)
  })

  stockstxt = stockstxtclosure()

  stockstxt = gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", stockstxt)
```

Error is:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
 (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside
 a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your code inside a reactive expression or observer, as the error states?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Actually isolate helps me.